# Microsoft Office 2010 Pro and Ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04, 64-bit, 32-bit, microsoft-office

I currently use x64 and I tried to install Microsoft Office 2010 Professional x86 & x64 and it failed with Wine and Play on Linux.

It says that it needs MSXML 6 SP1, yet installation fails every time. It says that it is not supported by the processor or that installation could not continue.

I can downgrade to x86, if that means that I can install Microsoft Office 2010?

Comment: No, you can not. It is a product for another operating system.  Libre Office is not an option why exactly? Besides visual basic for macro's where you need can use python in LO it is pretty much the same. It even supports docx.

Comment: The instructions to install Microsoft Office 2010 professional using wine (play on linux is not mentioned here). Scroll down the page to the "how to" section. https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=17336&iTestingId=84438

Comment: successfull installation of MSoffice 2010 on this thread: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1885051

Comment: @Rinzwind don't ever listen to anyone who tells you that you can't do something in linux. If it doesn't work now, we will make it work :)

Comment: @ScottSquibbles There's  no need to downgrade Ubuntu to x86; you can cofigure wine and office to run as x86 instead.